# AzPowerShell VMs migrated through Arc don't have an OSProfile property

Tags: powershell, azure

We have a mix of VMs that were created inside Azure, and VMs that were migrated from on-prem to Azure using Arc.

In AzPowershell, the information I need (computername) is in the OsProfile property. Here's a code snippet I use:

```
$(Get-AzVM -VMName "Server1").OsProfile.ComputerName
```

For systems built in Azure, the "OsProfile" property exists, and running this snippet returns the server's hostname.

For systems migrated through Azure Arc,  the OsProfile property is blank, and the snippet returns no data.

Is there a reason why this OsProfile property would be blank for Arc systems? The data is present in the Azure Portal's GUI, but not in Powershell.

Note that the "OsProfile.Computername" property can be different from the "Name" property. In fact, this code snippet is used to track down this discrepancy.

Comment: See if you can work it out with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.connectedmachine/get-azconnectedmachine?view=azps-11.0.0 for those machines and that value as a workaround. I don't know the difference personally but I see `Get-AzVM` use `Az.Compute` module if that matters for the difference from the queried hosts, M365 subscription, etc.  I don't use Azure Arc or have anything to test, and no access to any Azure VMs at the moment either.